# best approach for multiple tabbed gridviews

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to create multiple gridviews in which all would be loaded at pageload. I have 3 sets of data. When user clicks on a tab then it would show the corresponding gridview.

What is the best approach to this? I'm not good at JavaScript or JQuery.

One way I thought of is using a table and image buttons, where I would put gridview1.visible = false when gridview2 tab is clicked. Is this a good way to do it? or is there another intuitive way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Easiest approach to use Ajax Tookit Tab Containers and Tab Panels, Put GridView in the content template of TabPanel.

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" 
        OnClientActiveTabChanged="ClientFunction" 
        Height="150px">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" 
        HeaderText="Signature and Bio"
        <ContentTemplate>
           -- Grid View -- 
        </ContentTemplate>
    />
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Refer :
http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/Tabs/Tabs.aspx